# How to update one row between DateFrom and DateTo, when I have two changes in the same day?

Tags: sql, sql-server

#FinalChangeSet collects data from 3 history tables: #tmpEmployeeHistory, #PayrollHistory and #ContractHistory. Basically when I have a change recorded in one of those tables, I insert the PersonId and ChangeDate (which is DATE_FROM from the history tables) in #tmpFinalChangeSet.
 After the data collection, I have to complete the image of the lines in #tmpFinalChangeSet, with updates from those 3 tables. For instance each line in #tmpFinalChangeSet has a StatusId(EmployeeHistory), GrossIncome(PayrollHistory), ContractID(ContractHistory). Each line from #tmpFinalChangeSet has to be updated on StatusId, GrossIncome and ContractId, so that we know, in each moment in time (ChangeDate) what is the info associated with that PersonId.
I can expect 2 changes in the same day only in #EmployeeHistory, that's why I have DaySeqNum column, to record which was first. If for a PersonId we have 2 changes in the same day, both of them go in #tmpFinalChangeSet, because we expect a different StatusId.

**#EmployeeHistory**

| PersonId | Date_From | DateTo | DaySeqNum | StatusId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2018-06-01 | 2018-12-16 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2018-12-17 | 2018-12-17 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2018-12-17 | 2019-04-30 | 2 | 5 |
| 1 | 2019-05-01 | 2019-07-31 | 1 | 1 |

**Expected result set:**

| Id | PersonId | ChangeDate | DaySeqNum | StatusId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2018-06-16 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2018-12-17 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 2018-12-17 | 2 | 5 |
| **4** | **1** | **2019-01-01** | **1** | **5** |
| 5 | 1 | 2019-05-01 | 1 | 1 |

And I need to fill StatusId in **#tmpFinalChangeSet**. The Update below won't affect line 4.

```
UPDATE t SET
    t.StatusId = eh.StatusId 
FROM #tmpFinalChangeset t
JOIN #tmpEmployementHistory eh ON EH.PERSON_ID = T.PersonId 
    AND T.ChangeDate >= EH.DATE_FROM
    AND T.ChangeDate <= ISNULL(EH.DATE_TO, '99991231') 
    AND EH.DaySeqNum = T.DaySeqNum
```

The result set

| Id | PersonId | ChangeDate | DaySeqNum | StatusId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2018-06-16 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2018-12-17 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 2018-12-17 | 2 | 5 |
| **4** | **1** | **2019-01-01** | 1 |  |
| 5 | 1 | 2019-05-01 | 1 | 1 |

The `and EH.DaySeqNum = T.DaySeqNum` was added so I wouldn't get the same result for ChangeDate = '2018-12-17' - which would've been StatusId = 1 (first line encountered)

I need two uniquely identify each ChangeDate between DateFrom and DateTo in #EmployeeHistory. But because sometimes I have 2 changes in the same date (eg:'2018-12-17') I can't just use *between and* in the on clause of the join. I  need some sort of conditional JOIN statement, that I can't figure out right now. 
Hope it's a bit clearer now, apologies for the long text. :)

**Later edit**: My only solution was two separate update statements. Pretty much I use the statement above twice, only difference being that the first time I don't have `and EH.DaySeqNum = T.DaySeqNum` . That works just fine, because I'll correct any line with DaySeqNumb = 2 in the next update, which would've left line 4 in my example outside. 
I'm still looking for a better way to do this. (tbh I was thinking of a second way: dateadd-ing 1 second to the ChangeDates with DaySeqNum = 2, which would help me uniquely identify each date.)

Comment: is your first table the sample data and the second your expected outcome ? Or are they both sample data ? Can you explain a bit more clear please

Comment: Please add all relevant data in your question, not in comments. This is to much information hidden in the comments, people that read your question need to find all information in the question without having to read all comments

Comment: Hopefully, you can get a better idea now. If It's still a bit unclear, please let me know. I still have some trouble with posting questions, because of the code format error. :)

Comment: It is still not clear what you want to achieve, maybe this [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KJHa5juo) can help ?

Comment: Alright. Basically what we should obtain, is lines 3 and 4 from #tmpFinalChangeSet have StatusID= 5. [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-E2L8cQS)

Comment: I don't get what your logic must be, why is line 2 not set to StatusID = 5 ? See [this DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AxfrkgeY)

Comment: Because I have 2 changes in '2018-12-17'. And when I have to changes in the same day, I use Day Sequence Number in the join clause, in order to have the correct StatusId. (take for instance, my employee was first Active (1), then Suspended(5). And obviously, the second line is the one in effect, but I need to have the whole history accurate.

Comment: So why is line 2 then not 5 ? Can you explain the logic more in detail, I cannot help you if I don't understand what you want

Comment: Because on line 2 StatusId should match that of the first change recorded in '2018-12-17' - '2018-12-17' (DaySeqNum = 1). I tried to make my question clearer, If you could please give it another full read, maybe it will make more sense :)

Comment: Do you mean to update the status when second, or later, changes happen on a date ? If so, take a look at this [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/f_n3bIDJ).

Comment: Well, not just like that, because I have multiple StatusIds and PersonIds. Basically I wanted to uniquely identify identify each row from #tmpFinalChangeSet within an interval (date_from - date_to) from #EmployementHistory. My only solution so far, is two separate updates, first without, second with the and eh.DaySeqNum = t.DaySeqNum clause.